# Understanding a Quantile-Quantile Plot

Tags: r, distributions, quantiles, qq-plot

I must have generated at least 5 Q-Q plots until now when trying to fit my data into a known distribution but I just noticed something that I could not understand. In the figure shown below, from what I've read from the wiki, X-axis is supposed to read "Negative Binomial Theoretical Quantiles" and Y-axis is supposed to read "Data quantiles". Agreed that this makes perfect sense. But when I looked at the figure, the X and Y axis go beyond 100 but how can there be quantiles beyond 100? What do they mean if they exist? Or is this graph produced by the qqplot of R totally different? Can someone help me understand this?

The way I was generating this data was using the following script:

```
library(MASS)

# Define the data
data <- c(67, 81, 93, 65, 18, 44, 31, 103, 64, 19, 27, 57, 63, 25, 22, 150,
          31, 58, 93, 6, 86, 43, 17, 9, 78, 23, 75, 28, 37, 23, 108, 14, 137,
          69, 58, 81, 62, 25, 54, 57, 65, 72, 17, 22, 170, 95, 38, 33, 34, 68, 
          38, 117, 28, 17, 19, 25, 24, 15, 103, 31, 33, 77, 38, 8, 48, 32, 48, 
          26, 63, 16, 70, 87, 31, 36, 31, 38, 91, 117, 16, 40, 7, 26, 15, 89, 
          67, 7, 39, 33, 58)

# Fit the data to a model
params = fitdistr(data, "Negative Binomial")

#using the answer from params create a set of theoretical values
plot(qnbinom(ppoints(data), size=2.3539444, mu=50.7752809), sort(data))
abline(0,1)
```

[image]

Comment: Please do *not* cross-post simultaneously on SO and here.

Comment: @Dirk Eddelbuettel: Deleted my other post. I wasn't sure if this comes under programming or pure statistics.. Anycase, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I came across [this article](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Ricci-distributions-en.pdf) regarding QQ plots and various distributions and thought you may appreciate reading through it.

Comment: @Chase: Awesome! Looks like it discusses a number of things. I'll read it right away. +1 Thank you very much.

Comment: As it happens, I'm working on a very similar problem, with about the same experience level. Have you taken into account that your data appear to be left- or zero-truncated? Also, in addition to negative-binomial, have you considered the beta binomial or geometric distributions for your count data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think R is doing perfectly what you want it to do.

You are plotting:

> x = qnbinom(ppoints(data),
>   size=2.3539444, mu=50.7752809)

which is:

> [1]   3   5   7   9  10  11  12  13 
>   14  15  16  17  18  19  20 [16]  21 
>   21  22  23  24  25  25  26  27  28  28
>   29  30  31  31 [31]  32  33  34  35 
>   35  36  37  38  39  39  40  41  42  43
>   44 [46]  45  45  46  47  48  49  50 
>   51  52  53  54  55  56  57  59 [61] 
>   60  61  62  63  65  66  68  69  71  72
>   74  76  77  79  81 [76]  84  86  89 
>   91  94  97 101 105 110 116 123 132 146
>   175

with respect to

> y = sort(data)

which is:

> [1]   6   7   7   8   9  14  15  15 
>   16  16  17  17  17  18  19 [16]  19 
>   22  22  23  23  24  25  25  25  26  26
>   27  28  28  31 [31]  31  31  31  31 
>   32  33  33  33  34  36  37  38  38  38
>   38 [46]  39  40  43  44  48  48  54 
>   57  57  58  58  58  62  63  63 [61] 
>   64  65  65  67  67  68  69  70  72  75
>   77  78  81  81  86 [76]  87  89  91 
>   93  93  95 103 103 108 117 117 137 150
>   170

Therefore, you have 100+ values on both the axis. If you want to plot quantiles, you need to tell R to do so by doing this:

> plot(pnbinom(sort(data), size=2.3539444, mu=50.7752809), ppoints(data))

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot for your time and explanation. I have accepted this as an answer but can you kindly explain how to interpret my original graph?

Comment: @Legend. As I pointed out, your graph plots the sorted data points (y in our case) vs the corresponding values of negative binomial random variable which correspond to the value of probabilities `ppoints(data)` in your case. Therefore, the last point in your graph is (175, 170) which is below the `abline(0,1)`.